# Command Line Utility for registering 32-bit and 64-bit components to HKCU

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry

I am looking for a command-line utility that comes in 32-bit and 64-bit versions,  that will do the following:

- register com dlls and controls in either LOCAL MACHINE or CURRENTUSER
- does not require admin rights to run
- extracts registry info of input dll or ocx into a REG file

...I was told by someone in another community that a utility like this is impossible to write and does not exist. I suspect not; Embarcadero's tregsvr.exe does the above except for extracting registration info, and the RegSvrEx utility from the codeproject even has a [64-bit version now](https://github.com/vadz/RegSvrEx). Visual Studio's REGCAP.EXE does the last thing only.